# Align content below a marker in new line

Tags: equations, align, alignment

I am trying to write solutions to some problems. And for that I have to break the lines sometimes and start writing after some indent. eg. I want to break line after second `=` in line 2 of following,

[image]

To achieve that I used following code,

```
\TheSolution{Share of a man, a woman and a boy, $= 9 : 8 : 4$\\
    \begin{align*}
    \text{Share of 4 men, 5 women and 6 boys,} &= 4*9 : 5*8 : 6*4\\
    &= 36 : 40 : 24
    \end{align*}
    Share of 5 women,\[ = 425 * \frac{40}{36+40+24} = \text{\rupee}~170\]
    Share of a woman, \[= \frac{170}{5} = \text{\rupee}~34\]
}
```

[image]

But this does not seem feasible as it's breaking the indentation and adding additional margins. And last but not least, `That's a lot of code for such simple task`. Is there any alternative to achieve the right indent in less code?

Comment: I would recommend you use a _single_ `align*` environment and use `intertext{}` or `\shortintertext{}` for the text part. I think you may also need to use the `mathtools` package (this includes `amsmath).